# how to connect cassandra from local to EC2 instances

Tags: amazon-ec2, cassandra, phpcassa

I installed cassandra cluster in ec2 its working correctly. but when i try to connect the cassandra from code using php_cassa lib. its throwing error like "no server available"

the follow code its am working.

'ec2-public-ip address', 'port' => 9160);
$conn = new Connection('CookieDB', $servers);
$column_family = new ColumnFamily($conn, 'User');
$column_family->insert('row_key', array('username'=>'PHPCASSA'));
$value = $column_family->get('row_key');
print_r($value);
?>

is there anything am doing wrong

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

sounds like you didn't edit rpc_address in cassandra.yaml to listen on the public interface instead of localhost.

Answer (score -1):

1. Goto EC2 Management Console
2. Click on Security Groups under Network and Security on the left menu
3. Select your Security Group associated with your instance and click on Inbound Tab
4. Find out what is the source for ALL Port (Service).  If the source is sg-xxxxxxxx, then delete the same.
5. Add a new rule by selecting the below options:
   Create a new rule:  All Traffic
   Source: 0.0.0.0/0
6. Add Rule and click on Apply Rule changes
7. To verify if you are able to connect to Cassandra server, run the cassandra client from your local machine like below:

> > cassandra-cli -host ec2-XX-XXX-XX-XXX.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com -port 9160

Comment: Opening all ports to the world is overkill. 9042 and 9160 are sufficient, plus 8888 if using OpsCenter and 22 for SSH access.